# Concrete 5 login redirect

Tags: redirect, authentication, concrete5

I am trying to implement a login in my single page. But after login it is redirected to the root.

For example my link is `assessment/adsjh8nf3k`, `assessment` is the controller and `adsjh8nf3k` is the get parameter. I would like to have a login that will stay or redirect back to my working page `assessment/adsjh8nf3k`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

A link to the login page can accept a Get parameter rcID, which is the collection ID of the page you want to go to after a successful login.

Comment: I implemented successfully the rcID, thanks for the help @JohntheFish. How about additional get parameter except from the rcID, variable like product_id to display its details after login (ex. "assessment/adsjh8nf3k/product_id")

Comment: You could implement such by overriding the core login code and propagating the parameters onwards.